# How to integrate Azure Key Vault with Terraform Script?

Tags: terraform, azure-keyvault

I want to use Terraform Script to store Certificate and renew Certificate if it's expired on Azure Key Vault. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: What have you tried already? Is there any terraform code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think time rotation is supported on certificates. Where as it is on security keys.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_password#rotate_when_changed